# Procedure is not getting created in postgres11

Tags: pgadmin-4, postgresql-11

I am getting below error while creating simple stored procedure in postgresql-11,

ERROR: syntax error at or near "create"
LINE 4: create or replace procedure transfer(

How to solve this error?

See the screenshot for more info.
[image: SCREENSHOT]

Comment: run your statement in the SQL query tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ran in the query tool got few syntax errors after rewriting as below executed successfully:

```sql
create or replace procedure transfer()
language plpgsql    
as $$
DECLARE
begin
    Select now();
END $$;
```